# how to import geopandas in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

In the anaconda prompt, I created the environment mymap and installed geopandas with:
`create --name mymap geopandas`
then activated my environment mymap with:
`conda activate mymap`
checked that geopandas was installed with:
`conda search geopandas`
Then launched the jupyter notebook and typed:
`conda activate mymap`
and
`import geopandas as gpd`
but it gave: no module named "geopandas"

How to activate the environment mymap in jupyter and import geopandas?

Comment: How did you launch Jupyter?If you had launched it from terminal where your's conda env is activated - you would have been able to import it.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I launched it from a command prompt. Jupyter is not recognised in the Anaconda prompt.

Comment: I just found out that I can launch it by clicking on the Jupyter Notebook icon installed by Anaconda in the start menu (Windows). However import geopandas does not work...

Comment: In the anaconda prompt window, if I do: cd anaconda3\Scripts and launch jupyter-notebook, many errors come out (Error: DLL load failed while importing error). How can it be so complex?

Comment: `conda search` doesn't check that you have installed anything. instead it shows you what you _could_ install. you want `conda install geopandas --channel=conda-forge`

Comment: Thank you Paul, but I already tried  `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas` and it took too much time. But I understood that `conda create --name mymap geopandas` creates an environmment called mymap and installs geopandas. Is this incorrect?

Comment: And I can see in the directory ...\anaconda3\envs\mymap a number of directories (Lib etc) and DLLs, so I thought it was installed in this environment, and my problem was to tell jupyter to look at this environment. In a previous attempt, I used pip and installed 5 packages following the example of [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNPETGKAe0c) and this apparently worked: to check it, I launched py in a command prompt, typed `import geopandas as gpd` and then `help(gpd)`and it seems to be OK